# Is any open set star-shaped with respect to a given point within it?

Tags: geometry

A set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be *star-shaped with respect to a point $x_0\in S$* if for any point $x\in S$ the line segment joining $x_0$ to $x$ lies entirely in $S$.

My question: Given an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a\in U$, is $U$ star-shaped with respect to $a$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider an open annulus in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: No, but every $a \in U$ has a star-shaped neighborhood in $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any dimension, consider the union of two disjoint open balls.